# How to add a new tab into navindex using doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate an API documentation, and want to add some tutorials (will be wrote in the dox files).

I would like to add a new tab "Tutorials" into navindex.

How should I achieve this? Is it possible to use Examples as the Tutorials?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem following the suggestions in this blog: http://matthewtyler.io/adding-tabs-in-doxygen/

```
<tab type="user" url="@ref licence" visible="yes" title="Licence"/>
```