# With doxygen, how to avoid duplicate entries in the sidebar when using custom tabs in the navindex?

Tags: doxygen

I have a bunch of Doxygen `@page`s, starting with a top-level `@page moco Moco`, which automatically shows up in the sidebar. To make these pages prominent, I edited my `doxygen-layout.xml` to include `<tab type="usergroup" url="@ref moco" visible="yes" title="Moco" intro="">` under `<navindex>`. This has the desired effect of adding a `Moco` navigation tab to the top. However, `Moco` now appears twice in the sidebar.

[image]

Is there a way for me to remove either one of the instances of `Moco` in the sidebar while retaining the `Moco` navigation tab?

Related: [How to add a new tab into navindex using doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689148/how-to-add-a-new-tab-into-navindex-using-doxygen)

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use?

Comment: @albert, I used doxygen 1.8.18.